# QGIS Reprojecting csv point file to projected CRS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, csv

Using QGIS 2.10.1 I am importing a csv point file into a project in CRS World_Gall_Stereographic (EPSG:54016) (shapefile layers correctly reprojected and saved as new shp files beforehand). I am working on a global scale and need meter as units, so this projection was recommended as the best.

Importing the csv file and choosing EPSG:54016 as CRS, the results I am getting are completely off, the points are displayed in the wrong place and in a completely wrong scale. Opening the csv point file in a new project with EPSG:54016 gives me good results, saving it as shp file works but importing it into the work project gives the same odd results. I have played with OTF activated or not, but no changes either.

Here are some pictures to illustrate the problem:

[image: World map in WGS84, purple dots correctly displayed point shp file]
[image: World map reprojected to ESPG:54016, orange dot is reprojected point shp file]

This is a sample of my data in csv format:

MMSI,TIME,LONGITUDE,LATITUDE
1001,20120601_100157,165.7150667,52.6985
1001,20120601_124723,166.1643833,52.9314
1001,20120601_124723,166.1643833,52.9314
1001,20120601_220220,165.7496667,52.85125
1001,20120601_220519,165.7520667,52.8536
1001,20120602_235323,165.9094167,52.95831667
1001,20120603_112921,165.7208,52.83848333
1001,20120603_113224,165.7075833,52.83575
1001,20120603_130453,165.7627167,52.899
1001,20120603_144053,165.8316,52.97681667
1001,20120603_161908,166.0608833,53.03563333
1001,20120604_092627,166.1136333,52.93046667
1001,20120604_092927,166.1053833,52.9295
1001,20120604_113524,165.7658667,52.8703
1001,20120604_163411,166.45675,53.03293333
1001,20120605_003227,166.3319667,52.98035
1001,20120605_134348,166.2827667,52.9799
1001,20120605_165256,166.3453333,53.01598333
1001,20120605_231128,166.1088,52.96871667
1001,20120606_092004,166.8022833,53.21533333
1001,20120606_135901,167.9537667,53.59735
1001,20120606_171113,168.7523167,53.86685
1001,20120607_095605,170.53445,55.15393333
1001,20120607_100243,170.53395,55.13795

Something tells me I might be overlooking something or making a mistake with the reprojection.

Comment: Is your source CSV file already reprojected into SRID 54016, or is the source data in latitude/longitude (WGS84), and you'd like to reproject it into 54016? Could you paste the top few rows of your CSV file?

Comment: The source csv is in lat/long and I'd like to reproject it, already wondered if the reprojection might be the problem. I added a data sample to my question above.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to reproject data from one CRS to another, **DO** **NOT** simply change the CRS with `Set CRS for Layer`. This will **NOT** reproject any coordinates. So please change the CRS back to EPSG:4326 since that is the correct CRS for your lat/lon data.

Instead, use `Save As...` to another file name and CRS. You might want to use `ESRI Shapefile` format, since CSV does not store CRS information inside the file.

Comment: Thanks AndreJ, I am aware of this. As maybe not made clear above, I did save it in the new CRS when converting it to a shape file. I am puzzled why this goes wrong, as the shapefile should hold the information for the new projection.

Comment: Under `Settings -> Options, CRS` tab, set CRS for new layers to `Prompt for CRS` to avoid any automated missettings for the CRS. The extent of the shapefile should be much larger than +/- 180/90. You can look it up under Layer Properties, metadata tab.

Comment: If the CRS for the CSV is set to anything other than 4326 _before_ you reproject it, the reprojection won't be correct. You have to select 4326 when you first import the CSV, or by using `Set CRS for Layer`, _then_ use `Save As...` to save as a shapefile. You want to select the Gall project in the `Save As...` dialog (third field in the dialog), and at no time before that.

Comment: Dericke, that worked! Thanks a lot! I am not sure why the program works this way and why I have stumbled upon this right now, but it seems that did the trick. Thanks!!!

Comment: And AndreJ, now I grasp what you were saying, thanks to you, too!