# Reprojecting a SHP in QGIS to used it in ERDAS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, erdas-imagine, reprojection-mathematics

I´m trying to created a AOI in ERDAS with a shapefile, but this shapefile had a projected system different to system that my image has, because of that I changed the projected system of the shp in QGIS. Now both (image and shapefile) have the same system, but they are not overlapping each other, I know they are from the same zone but it seems like I´m doing something wrong.

Should I change something else? Or did I something wrong in the process?
I followed this answer to re project the shp
[How can I change the projection of shapefile in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73686/how-can-i-change-the-projection-of-shapefile-in-qgis)

These are the characteristics of my image in ERDAS. 
[image: These are the characteristics of my images in ERDAS]
And these are the characteristics of my SHP in QGIS (After the change).
[image: And these are the characteristics of my SHP in QGIS]
And they look like that when I put them together
[image: And they look like that when I put them together]

Comment: You need to redefine the CRS of the AOI back to match what the data it was created from, and then project it to the image's CRS. For instance, see the answer on [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159458/qgis-reprojecting-csv-point-file-to-projected-crs).

Comment: If you add an Openstreetmap background, which dataset aligns to it? Most probably you misused `Set Layer CRS` when you shoudl use `Save As ...` to a different name and CRS.

Comment: Thanks for you comment @AndreJ. Actually I repeated the process and used `Save as` option and it worked. I was confuse with those two options