# How to identify proper CRS for new point layer?

Tags: qgis

I am having trouble aligning a new point layer. I created a new layer and uploaded a CSV UTF-8 file with the projection in my project but can't seem to get it to align properly. I am working with
EPSG:6499 - NAD83(2011) / Michigan South (ft) - Projected

Here are a few points I cant seem to align.

What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: That's decimal degrees, EPSG 4326.

Comment: see this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159458/qgis-reprojecting-csv-point-file-to-projected-crs)

Answer (score 1):

Data was in decimal degrees as Erik mentioned. I used EPSG 4326 and my points aligned correctly.